# Runnung Capistrano recipe with rbenv sudo

Tags: capistrano, rbenv

I'm trying to use rbenv sudo plugin within a Capistrano 2 recipe.
But, when I run it I'm asked to input the password so the recipe doesn't complete.

```
run "cd #{current_path} && rbenv #{sudo} bundle exec foreman export upstart /etc/init -a appa -u appaser -l ~/apps/appa/current/log"
```

Is there a way to use rbenv sudo with Capistrano?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the user you are running the command as can actually run sudo without having to provide the password.

Check out this post to see how to set that up: http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2008/01/27/passwordless-sudo/

Comment: First thanks for your reply. I have tried to setup the sudoers but without success. The command I wish to run from Capistrano passwordless is ```rbenv sudo bin/foreman export upstart``` what should I put in sudoers? Mine currently looks like ```deployser ALL=NOPASSWD:/home/deployerser/mapps/current/bin/foreman export upstart /etc/init*```. Thanks

Comment: Try removing /etc/init*

Comment: same result. Still asking for password. Thanks

Comment: You should try doing it manually to see if you are logged in as the said user, whether or not you are able to run the command with sudo.  In any case, it may be that you need to allow the server.  Btw, I noticed you have typo in the user name. It doesn't match the username for the home folder. That's not the reason is it?

Comment: The typo is just in my comment (not sure why it is there). The user is deployser and in my sudoers I now have ```deployser ALL=NOPASSWD:/home/deployser/mapps/current/bin/foreman``` and when I run from the terminal ```current$ rbenv sudo bin/foreman export upstart /etc/init -a mapps -u deployser -l ./log``` I'm asked for the password. Howerver if I run ```current$ sudo bin/foreman export upstart /etc/init -a mapps -u deployser -l ./log``` I get ```/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory``` so no password required in this case.

Comment: I have "solved" the issue by making all commands passwordless ```deployser ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL```. Is there any major issue with that?  Thanks